# Configuring an application for AppFabric

Tags: wcf, caching, workflow-foundation, appfabric

I am using AppFabric to implement caching. While configuring an application A using IIS Manager, I have imported the application in it. But after that, there is no Mange WCF and WF link in the IIS Manager. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

AppFabric consists of two main features : AppFabric Hosting and AppFabric Caching.

**AppFabric Hosting** help you to deploy and manage workflows (WF) or WCF services. Yes, it includes an extension of the Internet Information Services management tool that enables us to monitor the performance of services and workflow.

**AppFabric  Caching** in a in-memory distributed cache. It can be used in any application. Windows PowerShell is the exclusive management tool for this feature (no IIS). However you find find [here](http://mdcadmintool.codeplex.com/) a custom tool on codeplex.
AppFabric caching service is configured during installation and cache clients only need a few config to use it. [This post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx) from Scott can help you. This other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739548/appfabric-caching-examples-using-c-sharp) post can help you.

Comment: Did you mean to include a link to [http://mdcadmintool.codeplex.com/](http://mdcadmintool.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Scott's blog was very helpful!